# Started putting ceramic planks in home and got as far as putting the uncoupling membrane. Question, can I pull the membrane up and reuse it elsewhere?

Tags: flooring, installation, ceramic-tile, reuse

I got screwed. Paid someone to put ceramic tile in mobile home. He put self leveler down but he did not mix it correctly and it did not spread out and level out so the floor is not level and he proceeded to adhere the uncoupling membrane on top of the unlevel floor. I decided to put carpet back down and use the tile elsewhere in my home and was wondering if I can pull up the membrane (or some of it) and reuse it or if I have to call it a complete loss and purchase more and what are your thoughts or suggestions for underlayment for 3'x 6" tile planks in a small mobile home that always moves due to being on "no fill" land and next to railroad tracks? Thanks you kindly for all suggestions for I am in a catch 22. I am disabled and everything outside and in my kitchen and I just want my house back.

Comment: it is unclear why you are asking about your own ability ... you either are able to pull up the membrane, or you are not able to pull up the membrane ... only you can determine that

Comment: @jsotola  Think he wants to know if membrane is re-usable or a one time use before pulling it up.

Comment: First off I am a she and I am sorry for not being clear...Yes, I want to know if I pull it up, after it has been adhered, if it can be reused. Nothing has been put on top of it but it has been adhered underneath

Comment: My apologizes.  If it was glued down, probably can't be reused.  If just placed down or nailed, then it should be able to be reused.  Can always  try pulling up a corner first and see.